# Html5 video with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am just curious on how to display a video into a simple webpage using rails. I have try the following

```
<%= video_tag("video/trailer_test.mp4", :code:size => "320x240", :controls => true, :autobuffer => true)
```

But it didn't seem to do the trick. My file is located under public/video/trailer_test.mp4 but it won't work is there any reason why it shouldn't work? Note i only have an mp4 file at the moment.

This is the html created

```
<video controls="controls" height="240" width="320"><source src="video/trailer_test.mp4" /></video>
```

This is my path file

```
/home/jean/rail/map/public/video
```

and this is this is the name of my file

```
trailer_test.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced a similar problem few months ago. Try to give the path for the video between brackets - `[]`:

```
<%= video_tag(["video/trailer_test.mp4"], :size => "320x240", :controls => true) %>
```

Comment: I see the bar but when i press play nothing goes on. Is there anything  i am missing?

Comment: you should see the video as well... if you aren't seeing the video is because there is a problem with the path... Make sure that there a is a folder 'video' inside the `public` folder and the file name is correct. Also include the path between brackets.

Comment: Everything is the same, i was wondering should i declare it in my route.rb? Anything should be done to my config file?

Comment: if it is on the public folder you don't need worry about routes. Take a look on the page source generated by rais, it should have `src="video/trailer_test.mp4"`

Comment: Hmm it work fine if i give the full path of something else. such has follow http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/MPEG-4/vorbis-in-mp4/mi2_vorbis51.mp4

Comment: `/home/jean/rail/map/public/video` - the public folder is inside your application. You have many folder inside your application: app, config, doc, public, etc... the video should be there... Unless your application is called `map` the video is on the wrong place

Comment: well map is my application name, rail is just an extra folder because i have several testing rails, and map is the name of the current rails new map (application)

Comment: Found it, was http://localhost:3000/customers/video/trailer_test.mp4 so had to remove customers.

Comment: To those who encountered this problem - The rails video_tag will not work inside of the html video tag.